# GCP Uptime Checks to check private / internal endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, google-cloud-monitoring

I was wondering if anyone else has come across this problem, and if so, what solution was chosen.

We currently use GCP Uptime Checks for our internet facing endpoints - however, we do want to also use them to check non-internet facing endpoints (i.e locked down by a security group for example).

**Already considered:**

- Whitelist the GCP Uptime IPs - this was dismissed as we do not want to maintain a mass amount of IPs on our security groups - which may or may not change over time.
- Use GCPs new Private Uptime Checks - this only supports checking endpoints residing in GCP (we need to also check private endpoints in AWS)
- Set up a reverse NGINX Proxy VM - which we can lock down to GCP Uptime IPs (in one place, as opposed to multiple) - our services can then just whitelist the Proxy VM
- Try and achieve the same logic using the NGINX Ingress Controller in GKE

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could [Create private uptime checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/private-checks) for your GCP endpoints and use an [AWS connector project](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/settings/aws-accounts#connector-project) to import the metrics from your AWS endpoints.

Follow these steps provided in the [Quickstart for Amazon EC2](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-aws) guide to monitor your AWS endpoints:

1. [Create a Google Cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-aws#create-a-project)
2. [Connect an AWS account](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-aws#create-a-project)
3. [Authorize AWS applications](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-aws#provision-aws)
4. [Use Monitoring services with AWS](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-aws#using_stackdriver_services_with_aws)